# Python Glob search for specific filenames at the middle

Tags: python, filenames, glob

I have a folder with path

> /home/alperen/Desktop/test

and with files:

> 000001asdd.png
>   000005_C.png
>   000010-asda.png
>   000002gfg.png 
>   000006fkjfkj.png
>   .. etc

Here is my code portion to check specific files in this directory

```
for name in glob.glob("/home/alperen/Desktop/test/*001*.*"):
    print (name)
```

It gives correct output:

```
/home/alperen/Desktop/test/000012-asda.png
/home/alperen/Desktop/test/000001asdd.png
/home/alperen/Desktop/test/000010-asda.png
/home/alperen/Desktop/test/A000011-adsa.png
```

However when I try to use the following it does not work:

```
print(read_dir)        
for name in glob.glob(read_dir + "/*001*.*"):
    print (name)
```

It only prints read_dir itself and nothing else.

```
home/alperen/Desktop/test
```

Can anybody help me what is happening? Thanks.

Comment: `read_dir` is missing a slash, should be `/home/alperen/Desktop/test`.

Comment: where is `read_dir` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
for name in glob.glob("/" + read_dir + "/*001*.*"):
    print(name)
```

**Why:**

The`read_dir` is missing a leading `/` as it can be seen from the output:

```
home/alperen/Desktop/test
```

Where in the first case when you gave a complete path, it had a leading slash `/`, as it can be seen here:

```
for name in glob.glob("/home/alperen/Desktop/test/*001*.*"):
```

Comment: Thanks guys. I was missing slash at the beginning :)

Comment: @S.Alperen Great, you may mark the answer by clicking on the tick sign. cheers